# Attempting to 'Fit_Transform()' DataFrame results in "Input Variables with Inconsistent Numbers of Samples" Error

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, vectorization, tf-idf

I'm reading two columns of a .csv file into a Pandas dataframe using `pandas.read_csv()`. The head of the Dataframe is shown below:

```
        Year    cleaned
    0   1909    acquaint hous receiv follow letter clerk crown...
    1   1909    ask secretari state war whether issu statement...
    2   1909    i beg present petit sign upward motor car driv...
    3   1909    i desir ask secretari state war second lieuten...
    4   1909    ask secretari state war whether would introduc...
```

Following this, I call `df.dropna(inplace=True)`(thanks to [Brad Solomon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7954504/brad-solomon)) to allow the coming fit/transform calls to proceed without producing a 'MemoryError' as shown in my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49239943/memory-error-when-attempting-to-apply-fit-transform-on-tfidfvectorizer-conta).

Now that I have a memory-friendly form of Dataframe, I use SKLearn's `train_test_split()` to create four sets of data that I intend to use for fitting/transforming on to a Pipeline.

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df, df['Year'], test_size=0.25)
```

**The shape of these variables is:**

```
[IN] X_train.shape [OUT] (1785, 2)
[IN] X_test.shape  [OUT] (595, 2)
[IN] y_train.shape [OUT] (1785,)
[IN] y_test.shape  [OUT] (595,)
```

So, I have my data split into appropriate subsections for testing and training. I then create my Pipeline, which makes use of `TfidfVectorizer`, `SelectKBest` and `LinearSVC` as shown below:

```
pipeline = Pipeline(
    [('vectorizer', TfidfVectorizer(decode_error='replace', encoding='utf-8', stop_words='english', ngram_range=(1,2), sublinear_tf=True)),
     ('chi2', SelectKBest(chi2, k=1000)),
     ('classifier', LinearSVC(C=1.0, penalty='l1', max_iter=3000, dual=False))
    ])
```

Finally, we come across the error mentioned in the title when I attempt to call `fit_transform()` on the aforementioned X and y training data

```
model = pipeline.fit_transform(X_train, y_train)
```

...which in turn produces the error:

`ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [2, 1785]`

The full Traceback can be viewed [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxnZg.png).

Comment: Are you sure you are using the correct data for printing the shape and passing the same data. Also even if you solve this error, the LinearSVC doesn't have any `transform()` method. So calling `fit_transform()` on pipe will try to `invoke transform()` method of LinearSVC and you will get an error.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I'm not sure, I was previously using an alternate `train_test_split()` as shown: `X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df['cleaned'].tolist(), df['Year'], test_size=0.25)`, although a lack of completion leads me to believe it will result in a `MemoryError` i.e. it appears to run 'forever'. I'm heading out for a bit but will leave the process to run in the meantime.

Comment: I've arrived back some ~2 hours later to discover the process still running and hogging a vast amount of my system's RAM (almost 6GB), I'll attempt it without LinearSVC this time around and update you afterwards. Just to clarify, I'm using an alternate `train_test_split()` method as shown in the above comment, as opposed to that present in my original question. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

`inconsistent numbers of samples: [2, 1785]`
seems to indicate the rows and columns have been flipped in the pipeline.

try:

```
pipeline.fit_transform(X_train.T,
                       y_train.reshape((1785, 1)))
```

may need to `reshape` `y_train` see [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30813044/sklearn-found-arrays-with-inconsistent-numbers-of-samples-when-calling-linearre) and bear in mind the same transform will need to be applied to `test_X` and `test_y` before use.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I implemented your suggestion but was subsequently greeted by `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'lower'`. I've altered the `train_test_split()` to use `df['cleaned'].tolist()` as the first parameter as shown in the original post. I'm waiting for that to process the `fit_transform()` but I suspect it will result in a `MemoryError`.

Comment: This is actually a new problem which is progress! looks like one of your columns is an int type rather than a str type. try `df.column.astype(int)` or similar

Comment: Prior to fitting the training data on the Pipeline, I've entered `y_train.reshape((1785, 1)).astype(str)` which converts the dtype to `'<U21'` and replaces the `Pandas.Series` with a `Numpy.Ndarray`. However, this results in the same error: `'int' object has no attribute 'lower'`.